# Validate conformance object to protocol with associated type

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

This is my code:

```
protocol Protocol {
    associatedtype A
}

class Class: Protocol {
    typealias A = Int
}

assert(type(of: Class()) == Protocol.self)
```

The error is ofcourse:

> Protocol 'Protocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

I understand the error, but I hope there is some way to check if a given object conform to a protocol with an associated type, **without the need of  binding/casting**.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The issue is that `Protocol` isn't one type. It's a template for a type, where one type exists for every possible value of `A`.

Comment: @Alexander Maybe with reflection? I can't work it out though with Mirror...

Comment: Swift doesn't really have many reflection capabilities yet. The meta data necessary to do that at run time exists, and it's used by the debug tools, but an API hasn't been built to expose it yet. They're prioritizing ABI stability first.